# SwiftUI: AccessibilityLabel for Parent and Child views

Tags: swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to make the VoiceOver works in the next way:

When the user with VoiceOver swipes first I want to read the accessibility label of the VStack container and then switch to the elements inside and read them.

Is it possible?

[image]

I can only go through the all items inside and read them or focus only on container and read the container label.

But I really need to be able select the container and read the label first, and then select and read all items inside.